# How to automatically update variable when it changes on Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

We use `StreamBuilder` to update the UI when the data changes on Firestore. But I want to do a little different.

I want to *change a variable automatically when data change in Firestore* like `StreamBuilder`. How can I do it?

Comment: check `Stream.listen` / `Stream.forEach` methods and `Stream` official documentation in general

Comment: That sounds like the start of an answer @pskink :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do you think? OP does not think so... ;-)